# No output with jdeps when using -jdkinternals

Tags: java, jdeps

I am trying to use the [Java Dependency Analysis Tool (jdeps)](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDK8/Java+Dependency+Analysis+Tool). First I tried to do it with no arguments like so:

```
jdeps myJar.jar
```

It lists the dependencies that it uses. So far so good.

```
org.example (myJar.jar)
   -> java.io
   -> java.lang
   -> java.text
   -> java.util
   [...]
```

However, the biggest reason to use `jdeps` is to detect dependencies on packages that will not be accessible in Java 9 (e.g. `sun.*` packages). So I try to use the `-jdkinternals` flag, which checks for these incompatibilities. Thus my command is:

```
jdeps -jdkinternals myJar.jar
```

However, there is no output when I run this. Does this mean that it failed to run? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This means the jar does not use any JDK internal packages

Running `jdeps -jdkinternals` and getting no output means that `jdeps` did not find any JDK internal packages. You can verify this by running `jdeps` without `-jdkinternals` and looking at all of the listings of dependency packages. None of them will be internal ones.

It would probably be nicer for it to print "Found no JDK internal dependencies" to prevent confusion like this from happening. Still, know that no output means that there is nothing to worry about, so celebrate the fact that you won't have any issues when you use Java 9 (for this reason, anyway).